# Error after adding vhost to httpd.conf - centos

Tags: centos, vhosts

I added the following text to httpd.conf at the bottom:

```
<VirtualHost 12.34.56.78.80>
        ServerAdmin     foo@bar.com
        DocumentRoot    /var/www/html/some_dir/
        ServerName      foo-bar.example.com
        ErrorLog        /logs/foo-bar.example.com-error_log
        CustomLog       /logs/foo-bar.example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

..and then when attemping to run the following command:

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

I get the following error:

```
[error] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: Could not resolve host name 12.34.56.78.80 -- ignoring!
```

Note that names and the ip address have been changed for this post.

Comment: I have added "NameVirtualHost 12.34.56.78.80" above it all and that resolves the error, but cant seem to get the daemon to start..

Comment: The delimiter for the port number is :        You need to say 12.34.56.78:80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1100566) is the solution for Ubuntu, but the idea is the same.

Comment: needed to still add NameVirtualHost 12.34.56.78:80 before it all and recheck the path directives..

Answer (score 2):

It's a typo within your config.

Wrong: `<VirtualHost 12.34.56.78.80>`

Should be: `<VirtualHost 12.34.56.78:80>`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with CentOS server and spent like 1/2 day on investigation. Eventually got it fixed with 2 steps:

**STEP 1**

Make sure that firewall (iptables) doesn't block port 53. I added to

```
/etc/sysconfig/iptables
/etc/sysconfig/ip6tables
```

the following lines:

```
-I INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

restarted firewall

```
# service iptables restart
```

and then restarted Apache

```
# service httpd restart
```

And then I got again:

```
[error] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: Cou...
```

I restarted Apache again and this time the hosts could be resolved but unfortunately the website still didn't work. So I tried restarting Apache several times and the above error occurred randomly!

**STEP 2**

Nothing worked so I finally restarted the whole server

```
# /sbin/reboot
```

and voilà everything started working like a charm!